# ffmpeg convert H264 CFR + timestamps to VFR

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, h.264

I have a H264 video source that was recorded with variable framerate (VFR) and a text file with frame ID, timestamp pairs that looks like this:

```
frameId,timestamp
1890413473,13792093
1890413474,13792106
1890413475,13792123
1890413476,13792139
...
```

If I try to playback as is, it defaults to the 25 constant framerate (CFR) 
`ffmpeg -i stream.h264 -c copy stream.mkv`

How do I combine the timestamp data to make a .mkv playing at the appropriate rate? The docs have `-vsync vfr` which looks related, but not sure about the input format for the times to sync with.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893746

Comment: I wrapped the h264 in an mp4 container and changed the text file to the timecode v2 format. Then the [mp4fpsmod](https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod) was able to make the correct VFR video.
I was able to do a similar thing with [mkvmerge](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix) to work with mkv containers.

Comment: However, is there a way for `ffmpeg` to do this or be more attuned to it? For instance if I try to convert the corrected vfr video to another format `ffmpeg -i stream_vfr.mp4 -c copy stream.mkv` I get mismatch values between `pkt_duration`, `pkt_dts` from the original from `ffprobe -show_frames`